# text substitution {} does not work at scrapinghub

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapinghub

I create a url with {} format to change the url on the fly.
It works totally fine on my PC.
But once I upload and run it from scrapinghub one(state)  of the many substitutions(others work fine) does not work, it returns %7B%7D& in the url which is encoded curly braces.
Why does this happen? What do I miss when referencing State variable?

This is the url from my code:

```
def __init__(self):

    self.state = 'AL'
    self.zip = '35204'
    self.tax_rate = 0
    self.years = [2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017] 

def parse_m(self, response):
    r = json.loads(response.text)
    models = r['models']
    year = response.meta['year']
    make = response.meta['make']
    for model in models:
        for milage in [40000,50000,60000,70000,80000,90000,100000]:
            url = '****/vehicles/?year={}&make={}&model={}&state={}&mileage={}&zip={}'.format(year,make, model, self.state, milage, self.zip)
```

and this is the url i see in the log of scrapinghub:

```
***/vehicles/?year=2010&make=LOTUS&model=EXIGE%20S&state=%7B%7D&mileage=100000&zip=35204
```

Comment: Please indent you code properly. Also, if your for-loops are not inside any class method, the self.state will not return anything of value, and will probably not format your string the way you want.

Comment: Fixed indents. Not sure whay you mean by class methods. But as you see the self.zip variable works perfectly fine. Though they have the same formatting and usage as far as I see.

Comment: That seems really odd... A quick and dirty fix would be to just replace them with a `.replace('{}', '')` at the end of the url. Have you tried running this locally? How do you upload your code to scrapinghub?

Comment: Locally works well. I use shub deploy for uploading.

Comment: Please post your code, I also think that the problem is your `self.state` variable, might it be possible that it's changed somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a scrapinghub issue. It has to be your code only. If I do below

```
>>> "state={}".format({})
'state={}'
```

This would end up being

```
state=%7B%7D
```

I would add

```
assert type(self.state) is str
```

to my code to ensure this situation doesn't happen and if it does then you get an `AssertionError`